# Can I bubble up event from Master page to ASPX

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Can I bubble up a button click event of a button in master page to be handled by an event handler in the aspx page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rebroadcast the event. Declare a new corresponding event in your master page, such as `HelpClicked` and then aspx pages that use this master can subscribe to the event and handle it appropriately.  The master can also take a default action if there are no subscribers (or use an EventArgs with a Handled property or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

You can expose the event handler and hookup to it, like this:

In the master:

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClick
{
  add { ButtonThatGetsClicked.Click += value; }
  remove { ButtonThatGetsClicked.Click -= value; }
}
```

In the page:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnLoad(e);
  ((MyMasterType)Master).ButtonClick += MyHandler;
}

private void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Do Something
}
```

Also, you can avoid the Master type cast and have it already appear in intellisense as your Master's type by using the [@MasterType directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx) in the aspx markup.